# Naming variables and assigning values inside the loop in R

Tags: r, loops, variables

I have 90 variables:

```
x111 <- 23
x112 <- 54
...
x1130 <- 69

x2111 <- 149
x2112 <- 12
...
x2130 <- 45

x3111 <- 85
x3112 <- 105
...
x3130 <- 501
```

I need to calculate a sum of squares of each variable (SS), for example, *x111^2 + x112^2 + ...+ x3130^2*

The function I have is:

```
SSobs_calculator <- function(obs) {
obs_value <- (obs)^2
total_obs_value = total_obs_value + obs_value
return(obs_value)
}
```

The problem is I do not know how to pass variables. In the following code:

```
for(i in 1:90){
   SSobs_calculator(paste0("x1_11",i)
 }
```

would not work, because I can't pass variables that start with 
x1_2.. and x1_3... Also the index for each group goes to 30, and 90 will not be valid.

Should I join all variables into a data frame, and then square it? Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can get the values of the objects in a `list` with `mget`, then take the power and `Reduce` to a single number by taking the `sum` (`+`) of the `list` elements

```
Reduce(`+`, lapply(mget(ls(pattern = '^x\\d+$')), `^`, 2))
```

---

Or after getting the elements in a `list`, `unlist` and then do the `^` in a single step

```
sum(unlist(mget(ls(pattern = '^x\\d+$')))^2)
```

#### data

```
x111 <- 23
x112 <- 54
```

Comment: I am getting all elements in a list and squared, but when I am trying to sum up, I get an error: 'Error in sum(unlist(`+`, SSobs1l)) : invalid 'type' (builtin) of argument'

Comment: @FeyziBagirov  It is based on the assumption that all the objects in the global env followed by the pattern 'x' followed by some numbers.  Suppose you have some objects named as `x242 <- 'A'`, then it would also be in the `list` and it is a character class.  Please check if you have any objects like that in the global env